# zsh: command not found: heroku, after installing through npm

Tags: npm, heroku, npm-install, heroku-cli

I am trying to install the heroku-cli

I am on mac and I am using npm to install it.

```
npm install -g heroku
```

After installing I run the command `heroku` and the response I receive is:

```
zsh: command not found: heroku
```

I have been searching the internet for an answer for way too long now and can not seem to resolve this issue..

I have also downloaded the macOs tarbells and when I open the file, navigate to the bin folder and open the file "heroku" it opens my terminal and display this message.

[image: Terminal message]

Even after what looks like it has successfully been installed, when I type `heroku --version` I still get the command not found.

I am not the most experienced in this field. The reason I am trying to download heroku is because I am doing Fullstack Open.

I just hope it is an easy fix and someone more experienced than me can guide me in the right direction.

I should add I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times.

SOLUTION FOUND: The solution that helped me was installing homebrew and after installing I ran the command:

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: That second method appears to have worked. What's the problem?

Comment: For the NPM install, did you [add NPM's binary path to your `PATH`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/folders#executables)?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned even after that second command when i type heroku --version it still says zsh: command not found: heroku

Comment: For the second version you gave a full path to the executable: `/Users/blah/blah/heroku`. That works. So either add that directory to your path, or use the full version: `/Users/blah/blah/heroku --version`.

Answer (score 0):

heroku command not

```
npm i -g heroku
```

zsh: command not found npm:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
 [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
```

zsh: command not

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH
```